# Codeigniter - Set sessions based on row returned when checking user exists. Login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am making a CRUD area in a project, it needs to be protected by a login screen.

The logon check is working fine but I am having problems setting session variables.

So far I can set session variables but only to fixed values, how can I set the session values to the values being retrieved from the database. I have tried various methods and cannot find the solution on the internet.

I think the problem is that I'm losing the data from `$query` variable in my Model when it returns true, however I don't know how to pass it back with the row data.

Tried 
`$query->nombre`, 
`$query['nombre']`, 
`$this->$query['nombre']`

Yes, no form validation at this point.

CONTROLLER (I think the problem is here)

```
public function check_deets()
{
    $this->load->model('Admins');
    $query = $this->Admins->check_login();

    if($query)
    {
        $data = array(
                        'login' => $this->input->post('login'),
                        'nombre' => $query['nombre'],
                        'ultmiavisita' => $query['ultmiavisita'],
                        'is_logged_in' => true );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('horseadmin');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

MODEL

```
function check_login()
{
    $this->db->where('login', $this->input->post('login'));
    $this->db->where('clave', $this->input->post('clave'));
    $query = $this->db->get('admins');

    if($query -> num_rows() ==1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;

    }
}
```

Constructor function to redirect to login if sessions not set.

```
$is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
    {
      redirect('horseadmin_login');
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Well the constructor runs every time when you hit your controller, what you do is "install" any kind of auth library, use it and there is a method how to check if user is logged in or is not. It is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your check login function return false and true, not $query, try this

```
  function check_login()
 {
   $this->db->where('login', $this->input->post('login'));
   $this->db->where('clave', $this->input->post('clave'));
   $query = $this->db->get('admins');

  if($query -> num_rows() > 0)
  {
       return $query->row_array()
  }

    return false;

 }
```